# Почему появляется горизонтальный скролл на десктопе

Tags: css, адаптивная-верстка, прокрутка

Ширина макета 1366px, задала ширину ограничивающему контейнеру такую же - 1366px (верстаю макет desktop first впервые, до этого верстала только mobile first на курсах, при верстке mobile first нас учили задавать контейнеру для страницы ширину вьюпорта). Появляется горизонтальный скролл. В этой статье https://yoksel.github.io/bad-practices/containers/ говорится что нельзя задавать контейнеру ширину вьюпорта, но я раньше задавала и скролла не появлялось.Пробовала задать контейнеру ширину контента, хоть и в каждом блоке она разная, выбрала максимальную ширину, которая была в шапке- 1170px. Убрала все паддинги. Но и это не помогло, скролл никуда не делся. Что я делаю не так?

```
.page__body {
    background-color: $white;
    color: $dark-blue;
    font-family: "Montserrat", "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 23px;
    min-width: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .page__container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1366px;
  }
```

Макет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На самом деле все кто вам ответит, просто будут гадать, но обычно в этом виноват margin или border. внизу вон вам правильно посоветовали использовать box-sizing: border-box; - он включает в свою ширину разные border-ы, отступы(но не margin). Также нажав "CTRL + Shift + C" можно отследить, какой элемент выбивается за грани положенного.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи, а где эту комбинацию использовать?

Comment: @OliverPatterson на странице браузера

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи, оно просто вызывает devTools?

Comment: @OliverPatterson devTools это F12, а то что я написал - это одна из возможностей его, с которой можно просматривать элементы на странице просто водя курсором.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи, все понял, что это такое!) Не разу не пользовался коомбинацией.

Answer (score 1):

Прежде чем удивляться, стоит пробовать свои силы до тех пор, пока не выдохнешься...

```
*{ border: 1px solid red; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Если и так виновника не найдете... И да, ширина должна быть 100%, хватит слушать мамкиных верстальщиков.

Comment: Есть такой прикол, что вертикальный скрол забирает часть вью порта. От туда и появляется горизонтальный скрол. Указывайте 100% ширину и будет вам счастье